# How can I forward multiple ports in the SSH configuration with LocalForward?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I want to forward multiple ports. So far my configuration looks like this:

```
Host myhost
    Hostname 123.123.123.123
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_myhost
    LocalForward 8811 localhost:8811
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I would like to forward port 6006 in addition to 8811.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It is possible to add multiple lines of `LocalForward`:

```
Host myhost
    Hostname 123.123.123.123
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_myhost
    LocalForward 8811 localhost:8811
    LocalForward 6006 localhost:6006
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Is this what you want?